# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again. Appreciate any help

Tags: miktex, compilation-error, output, console

I checked the log file, it said as below:

> ```
> texify - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean myFileName.tex
> 664-0400 FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason.
> 664-0400 FATAL texify - Info: 
> 664-0400 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
> 664-0400 FATAL texify - Line: 1475
> ```

Comment: don't use texify if you have problems. Call pdflatex and other tools manually. That gives better error messages.

Comment: Ulrike, can you provide more details on how to do it, I mean on how not to use texify?  I am really new to MikTeX. Thank you.